# Adding "Advanced Search Button" next to search bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried many things but could not align "Advanced Search Button" next to search bar. You can see the pic below.

Here are codes I used

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <center>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group" style="width:90%;">
                        <input class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="ISBN, Yazar yada Kitap adı yazınız" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:1%;"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Advanced Search</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </center>

    </div>@*col-md-12*@

</div>@*row*@
```

Thanks
[image]

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the buttons a wrapper div with the class `.input-group-btn`.

Source http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-multiple

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap, try to use the class "pull-right" or "pull-left" depends on what you want.

there's the solution. I hope enjoy

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <center>
            <form>
                <div class="col-md-12" style="width:50%; margin-left:25%;">
    
    <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-group" >
                        <input class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="ISBN, Yazar yada Kitap adı yazınız" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:1%;"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
     <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">Advanced Search</button>
    </div>
    
                </div>
            </form>
        </center>

    </div>

</div>
```